# How to Get XML Second Child

Tags: php, xml

Can someone help me to get the second child of the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2013-03-27T03:39:01.575Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>815</Version>
  <Build>E815_CORE_API_15855340_R1</Build>
    <item>
    <ApplicationData>881030.B.0000</ApplicationData>
    <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
    <BuyerProtection>ItemEligible</BuyerProtection>
    <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">0.0</BuyItNowPrice>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
    <HitCounter>RetroStyle</HitCounter>
    <ItemID></ItemID>
    <ListingDetails>
      <Adult>false</Adult>
      <BindingAuction>false</BindingAuction>
      <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
      <ConvertedBuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ConvertedBuyItNowPrice>
     <ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
            <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">9.99</ShippingServiceCost>
     </ShippingServiceOptions>
     <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
            <ShippingService>StandardInternational</ShippingService>
            <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">39.99</ShippingServiceCost>
     </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
    <item>
```

I'm using a for look to cycle through all of the items (for $items as $item). I need to get the ShippingServiceCost from ShippingServiceOptions and InternationalShippingServiceOption.

I want to do the following but it doesn't work:

```
//for ShippingServiceOptions
$item->getElementsByTagName('ShippingServiceCost')->item(0)->nodeValue;

//for InternationalServiceOptions
$item->getElementsByTagName('ShippingServiceCost')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I think the problem is your unclosed `item` tag

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

since you've posted the full XML the php xml traversing will look like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
foreach($xml->item->ListingDetails as $child) {
    foreach($child->children() as $option) {
        if(isset($option->ShippingServiceCost)){
            echo $option->getName() . ": " . $option->ShippingServiceCost . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

The XML you posted has errors, in future please validate it before posting so we don't have to fix the errors :)

---

If you have PHP 5 +, you can use simplexml to parse your xml.
Also, you need to close your "item" xml tag.

Then the code becomes :

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
    foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
        echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child->ShippingServiceCost . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

xml :

```
<item>
 <ShippingServiceOptions>
        <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
        <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">9.99</ShippingServiceCost>
 </ShippingServiceOptions>
 <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
        <ShippingService>StandardInternational</ShippingService>
        <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">39.99</ShippingServiceCost>
 </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
</item>
```

output :

```
ShippingServiceOptions: 9.99
InternationalShippingServiceOption: 39.99
```

Comment: I'm having to use the ole $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response);

Comment: then use $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);   instead of simplexml_load_file('url.xml')

Comment: Hmm, in my original post I simplified the XML a litle. I've posted the full XML. The foreach($xml->children() as $child) returns timestamp, ack, version, build